# Json data bind wih table using jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am getting JSON data from my web method and want to display it on table with DataTables. I am using DataTables plugin. Now I want to add a edit link to table with a hidden field to hold the id for the data to be edited but I am failing to do this.

```
 "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
       "aoColumns": [
            { "mDataProp": "DesignationID","bVisible"  :false },
            { "mDataProp": "DesignationName" },
            { "mDataProp": "DesignationShortName" },
            { "mDataProp": "UserName" },
            { 
                "sWidth": "20px", 
                "sDefaultContent": 
                     "<input id='EditID' type='hidden' value=''>
                      <a name='lnkDelete'>Delete</a>", 
                "bSortable": false  
            },
```

What should I write in value part so that it get bind with DesignationID.  And on click to edit I get the value of DesignationID of the same row.

Comment: Have you looked at this https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
"sAjaxSource": "YOUR_AJAX_FILE.php",//here is your server file path
 "aoColumns": [
       { "mDataProp": "DesignationName" },
       { "mDataProp": "DesignationShortName" },
       { "mDataProp": "UserName" },
       { "mDataProp": "edit" },
       { "mDataProp": "delete" }
    ],
"aoColumnDefs": [
       { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 3 ] }, 
       { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4 ] },
    ],
```

HTML CODE:

```
<thead>
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2" width="215px">DesignationName</th>
    <th rowspan="2" width="215px">DesignationShortName</th>
    <th rowspan="2" width="100px">UserName</th>
    <th colspan="2" width="70px">Action</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
```

Add following html code to server file at end of file where data is retrieving from database.

```
   $row['edit'] = "<a href='YOURFILE_NAME.php?YOUR_FIELD_ID={$row['DesignationID']}'>Edit</a>";
   $row['delete'] = "<a href='#' name='lnkDelete' id='lnkDelete'>Delete</a>";
```

**Note:** for delete operation you can use id attribute and using the jquery ajax you can delete record and redraw the datatable.